# Batch File - If Exist Won't Work on Portable Hard Drive

Tags: batch-file

I've got a batch script to copy a folder from my computer hard drive to a portable hard. The problem I have is, when I run the IF EXIST on my portable drive it doesn't work, meaning it skips the check. The files copy from the computer drive to the portable just fine, but I want to verify it in my script, what I'm I doing  wrong?

```
::CLS
::@ECHO OFF

set myDir="C:\Users\Someone"
set userDir="userfolder"
set copyDrive="R:"



call:checkExist %myDir% %userDir%

pause
goto:eof

:checkExist
IF EXIST  %~1\%~2 (
    echo %~2 Exists 
    dir %~1\%~2 )   

    pause


    FOR /f "tokens=2-4 skip=1 delims=(-)" %%G IN ('echo.^|date') DO (
    FOR /f "tokens=2 delims= " %%A IN ('date /t') DO (
        SET v_first=%%G
        SET v_second=%%H
        SET v_third=%%I
        SET v_all=%%A
        )
    )

SET %v_first%=%v_all:~0,2%
SET %v_second%=%v_all:~3,2%
SET %v_third%=%v_all:~6,4%
SET DATE2=%MM%-%DD%-%YY%
mkdir %copyDrive%\%DATE2%
dir %copyDrive%\%DATE2%
cd %~1\%~2
pause
xcopy /e %~1\%~2 %copyDrive%\%DATE2%
```

**The IF EXIST below doesn't work. WHY!?**

```
IF EXIST %copyDrive%\%DATE2% (
    echo %DATE2% Exists
}
goto:eof
```

Comment: what do you expect the value of DATE2 to be?

Comment: Add `echo %copydrive%\%DATE2%` immediately before your IF EXIST test. You may be able to diagnose the problem yourself. If not, then report back (possibly edit question). You may need to provide actual paths and/or additional code to allow others to track down the problem.

Comment: @dbenham- I believe it to be a problem with my portable hard drive. I tried this script with another drive and it works as intended.

Answer (score 0):

Examine your :checkExist procedure very carefully.

```
FOR /f "tokens=2-4 skip=1 delims=(-)" %%G IN ('echo.^|date') DO (
FOR /f "tokens=2 delims= " %%A IN ('date /t') DO (
    SET v_first=%%G
    SET v_second=%%H
    SET v_third=%%I
    SET v_all=%%A
    )
)
```

So - now you've set up `v_*`

```
SET %v_first%=%v_all:~0,2%
SET %v_second%=%v_all:~3,2%
SET %v_third%=%v_all:~6,4%
```

Why set most of them up again? Are you sure of your date format? Might leading zeroes be suppressed or replaced by spaces? The date format is localised - without specific examples of significant example dates presented, we're guessing.

```
SET DATE2=%MM%-%DD%-%YY%
```

Ah - setting `date2` to some format using `MM`, `dd` and `yy`. Perhaps it might be an idea to set those elements - maybe instead of re-setting the `v_*` values

```
mkdir %copyDrive%\%DATE2%
dir %copyDrive%\%DATE2%
```

Ah - using that date value. I'd guess `date2` contains `--` here, just quietly.

---

Revised batch given extra part-information and assuming `%date%` in format `ddd mm/dd/yyyy`

```dos
::CLS
::@ECHO OFF

set "myDir=C:\Users\Someone"
set "userDir=userfolder"
set "copyDrive=R:"

call:checkExist "%myDir%" "%userDir%"

pause
goto:eof

:checkExist
IF EXIST "%~1\%~2" (
    echo "%~2" Exists 
    dir "%~1\%~2" )   

    pause

    )

SET "DATE2=%date:~-4%%date:~-10,2%%date:~-7,2%"
mkdir "%copyDrive%\%DATE2%"
dir "%copyDrive%\%DATE2%"
cd "%~1\%~2"
pause
xcopy /e "%~1\%~2" "%copyDrive%\%DATE2%\"
```

Note that I've chosen to use a destination date of YYYYMMDD. Alter

```
SET "DATE2=%date:~-4%%date:~-10,2%%date:~-7,2%"
```

to

```
SET "DATE2=%date:~-10,2%-%date:~-7,2%-%date:~-4%"
```

if you insist on having MM-DD-YYYY dates.

Note the positioning of qutes. The format `set "var=value"` is designed to ensure stray spaces are ignored.

Comment: @Magoo- I wanted to use the date as the name of my directory. I used Google to find the code, maybe this code isn't the best solution. What would be better?

Comment: It's normal to derive a date from the *magic* system variable `%date%` using `set date2=%date:~-4%%date:~-7,2%%date:~-10,2%` **but** all depends on your local date format (mine would be for dd/mm/yyyy dates) and desired destination format. A standard format is `YYYYMMDD` as this is unambiguous and lends itself easily to sorting. Without knowing precisely how **your** system presents dates, it's not possible to advise. You may have a system with 2 or 4 year digits, (long) dayname or no, different element sequence and separator or leading-zero suppression.How would your system show Mar 9?

Comment: Command prompt shows today's date as Tue 12/16/2014. I was just wondering, is something wrong with the for loop? It does exactly what I need it to do.

Comment: I asked for Mar 9 for a reason. It shows month & day & would show whether the month/day number was displayed with leading-zero, suppresses-leading-zero or space-replaces-leading-zero. Your reported date shows `Day MM/DD/YYYY` format. You should be able to extract the date `date2` from that format as `set /a date2=%date:~-4%%date:~-7,2%%date:~-10,2%` Your code was not setting `mm`, `dd`, `yy` so `date2` would be incorrectly set. There is no way in which `cmd` can determine that `MM`=`V_FIRST` for instance. The `for` loops are fine - just not setting the right variables & are too complex.

Comment: Alright, so my intention was to use the current date as the name of my newly created directory, how would you do it?